Why does the 'this' keyword change what it refers to?
Let's take the following short program as an example:
var Space = Space || (function(){
    return {
        recursive: function(){
            console.log(this);
            setTimeout(this.recursive, 1000);
        }
    }
})()

When I call Space.recursive(), why is the output:
{recursive: f}
Window{...}

and not
{recursive: f}
{recursive: f}
{recursive: f}
...

When I replace setTimeout(this.recursive, 1000) with setTimeout(Space.recursive, 1000) I get the desired result.

Because that is how it has been defined to work...

what kind of answer are you hoping for? The original motivations for designing the language this way?

why is this not bound to Space the second time through the method? Afterall it was bound to Space in the call.

Because the calls are not the same. Space.recursive() is not the same as x = Space.recursive; x(). Please, read the linked duplicates.

See the first of the list of duplicates. In short, for non-arrow functions this is defined at call time. obj.method() and f = obj.method; f() are not the same call.
